# BottomNavigationView does not hide on scroll - NestedScrollView in viewpager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-bottomnav

I have bottom navigation bar and viewpager inside coordinator layout, every fragment inside viewpager has own collapsing toolbars,

but `app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"` doesn't work for me.

Also I don't want to do `bottomNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);` by listening the my nested scrollviews (inside fragments), because it hasn't animation. this is my last option.

My Activity

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".market.MarketActivity">


    <com.example.x.custom.NonSwipeableViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
            app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
            android:theme="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"/>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

One of the fragments (In the content view there is an nested scrollview. I set its layout behavior)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".testproject.ScrollingActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:minHeight="56dp"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
                app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom|left"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="14dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="60dp"
                app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsingToolbarTextStyleBlack"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsingToolbarTextStyleBlack"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                android:background="@color/white">


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:titleMarginStart="0dp"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">



            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"

                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/warm_grey"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/lipstick"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayoutTextStyle"
                    android:paddingRight="6dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            >

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                        android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/main_market">

                </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem>

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                        android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/high_yield"/>

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                        android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/perpetuals"/>

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                        android:id="@+id/tabItem4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/special_situations"/>

            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>


        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_market"/>



</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Those links didn't work
[Hide/Show bottomNavigationView on Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777869/hide-show-bottomnavigationview-on-scroll)

[Show/hide BottomNavigationView on scroll in CoordinatorLayout with AppBarLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42631542/show-hide-bottomnavigationview-on-scroll-in-coordinatorlayout-with-appbarlayout)

[When scroll bottom navigation bar does not hide - BottomNavigationBehavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50495852/when-scroll-bottom-navigation-bar-does-not-hide-bottomnavigationbehavior)

[BottomNavigationView does not hide on scrolling inside fragment, if fragment contains AppBarLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54849905/bottomnavigationview-does-not-hide-on-scrolling-inside-fragment-if-fragment-con)

Answer (score 0):

it's too altho the

```
BottomNavigationView
```

is in the Activity so it's will work only if you are scrolling in the Activity.

you can do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44778453/7373745